# Need help in animating image slider

Tags: javascript

I have made this image slider. But I don't know how to make it animatable. Incoming slide should fade in and outgoing slide should fade out.
If someone could help me achieve that or point me in the right direction. It would be highly appreciated.
This is link to the codepen. https://codepen.io/dev1112/pen/WzKadd

```
// Set options
let speed = 500;    //fade speed
let auto = true;   //auto slider options
let auto_speed = 2000;  //auto slider speed

let slideImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slides li');

function nextSlide() {
  let activeImage = document.querySelector('.active-image');
  activeImage.classList.remove('active-image');
  activeImage.classList.add('old-active');

  let oldActive = document.querySelector('.old-active');
  if (oldActive === slideImages[slideImages.length - 1]) {
    slideImages[0].classList.add('active-image');
  } else {
    oldActive.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active-image');
  }

  oldActive.classList.remove('old-active');
}

slideImages[0].classList.add('active-image');

if(auto == true) {
    setInterval(nextSlide, auto_speed);
}
```

Comment: you can post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css animation to `.active-image` class.

```
.slides .active-image {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0 }
  25%,75% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

***DEMO***

```js
let slideImages = document.querySelectorAll('.slides li');

// Set options
let speed = 500;    //fade speed
let auto = true;   //auto slider options
let auto_speed = 3000;  //auto slider speed

function nextSlide() {
  let activeImage = document.querySelector('.active-image');
  activeImage.classList.remove('active-image');
  activeImage.classList.add('old-active');

  let oldActive = document.querySelector('.old-active');
  if (oldActive === slideImages[slideImages.length - 1]) {
    slideImages[0].classList.add('active-image');
  } else {
    oldActive.nextElementSibling.classList.add('active-image');
  }

  oldActive.classList.remove('old-active');
}

slideImages[0].classList.add('active-image');

if(auto == true) {
    setInterval(nextSlide, auto_speed);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 944px;

}

.slides {
  width: 100%;
  height: 531px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slides li {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}


.slides li img {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.slides .active-image {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: fade 3s linear;
}


@keyframes fade {
  0%,100% { opacity: 0 }
  25%,75% { opacity: 1 }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/7ci9i18i8fq6rgd/image1.jpeg" alt="image1"></li>
      <li><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/s809q74ozg4yp4r/image2.jpeg" alt="image2"></li>
      <li><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/10bkh141lpahtyw/image3.jpeg" alt="image3"></li>
      <li><img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6jm242t5rt18r34/image4.jpeg" alt="image4"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks durga .this is good solution but how can i make it stay for a few second at 1 opacity. it is happening so fast

Comment: @OmEr check update

Comment: thanks , it works great